# regex select a block of html code?

Tags: regex, select

I need to select a block of code so I can remove it using TextSoap.

How can I select everything from the opening "< !DOCTYPE" to the first "< h1>"?

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language?  What have you tried?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a proper parser?

Comment: Would you like to stop at the first `<h1>` even if it's inside javascript code?

Comment: Are you telling me [the mac-only tool for 40$ that you use](http://www.unmarked.com/textsoap/) does not even understand HTML?

Comment: It's a XHTML document that we need to convert to an XML document and we also need to remove everything before the article title.

Comment: @RichCoy then the most appropriate tool would most likely be a [XSLT (extensible stylesheet language transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) tool. XHTML is a subset of XML.

Comment: @RichCoy I'm not sure a X(HT)ML document should start with a doctype. It should start with `<?xml` or something like that.

Comment: @JanDvorak We are turning website articles into Stellent datafiles that will be imported into Oracle Stellent. That is why I need to select everything between the doctype and first h1, so I can then replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general regex could look like `'^<!DOCTYPE(.|\n)*?<h1>'` but like the commenters said correctly, what language are you using? Languages may have different ways of dealing with regexes. You can also try this: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: replace `*` with `*?`. Otherwise, it will match until the _last_ `<h1>`

Comment: would you ever have a HTML document that would have a header tag `<h1>` right after the `<!DOCTYPE...`? As the `?` would make it 'optional'.

Comment: The language he's using is a text editor for 40$, called TextSoap.

Comment: Umm, no, a `?` after a quantifier makes it non-greedy, not optional.

Comment: thanks for that! I corrected it, and learned a new thing!